# Any equivalent load circuit when an animal is connected to a current injector?

Tags: impedance

When the human body (chest, arm, etc) or an animal (limbs, belly, tail, etc) is connected to a circuit, I think this acts as a load.
[image: AED]
For instance, people simply model the connection between the AED (automated external defibrillator) and the human like this.

**Are there models to simply a human or an animal (mice, for instance) as a circuit?
Like the dry human skin mostly acts as a resistor with a parallel pF capacitor.**

Comment: Google for papers on "electrical equivalent of human bodies". You will find that a common approach is to attribute an impedance for each limb. Some papers provide approximate values for such impedances. So this comment is just to answer the question "are there models": "yes, there are models". To get a more relevant answer, you will need to be more specific regarding applications and precision levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are models, and standards that define them and tell you what usage the model is valid.

[This report from Underwriter's Laboratories (UL) show several models and refers to the standards defining them.](https://library.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/40/2017/12/UL-Report-on-Human-Body-Modeling-of-Heart-Current-Factor.pdf)

Example:

[image]

That image shows a couple of models, with the defining standard given in the text.

Basically a bunch of resistors and capacitors to simulate the body.

[There is a different, simpler model that is used for electrostatic discharge tests.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-body_model)  It is used to simulate what static discharge from a human body can do to an electronic circuit.

It is just a capacitor with a specific capacitance charged to a specific (high) voltage and a resistor through which the capacitor is discharged into the device under test.

Answer (score 0):

The human body is mainly dielectric with partial conductance from salts.

? 98% water by mass ?

Water has a dielectric constant of 80. 
The saline content makes it a lossy insulator.

Dry skin makes it a good insulator but depends on pressure of conductor content and interface if electrically conductive ( sweat or silver particle gel-pad or conductor probe area)

A small area can create high current density causing a sensation like ESD zap or heat rise or burn depending on this current density and duration. But let's ignore that for now.

I believe Defib's and Pacemakers are measured in mJoules of energy. We can compute this from E=1/2CV² and transfer half of the energy with up to half lost in the charge transfer interface from contact resistance.  Where a heart only needs mA, the chest needs Amps of current enough to energy all the nearby body muscles to contract.  The current is due to the  ΔV/R for the interface resistance.

Thus if you know the energy to excite a frog's leg or a heart muscle and interface resistance, you can compute the stored Cap dump capacitance and voltage required to deliver that energy and from the current density limit the size of the electrode.

In the case of an inductive pulse generator, you can compute the voltage from V=LdI/dt for a given contact dI= V/ESR and the energy from 1/2 LI² stored with losses.

The charge times and discharge times may be computed easily to get RC=T for 64% of V and energy \$ E= ∫Pdt\$ for the time duration of the pulse.

This hypothetical simulation of an inductive muscle *[pulser](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html)* which results in a damped resonant pulse of high V with 1/2 the energy lost in the contact resistance (unavoidable) then dumped into the lumped capacitance of the muscle which has some contraction force and thus resistance (not shown).

With a suitable choice of RLC's you can simulate the heart QRST waveform exactly.

[image]

The above is a simple 1st order approximation.

However, **[this model](http://www.medigraphic.com/pdfs/inge/ib-2011/ib112e.pdf)** of the muscle after several layers of skin appears as a high order LPF with each layer  modelled from Bode Plots about ω~1 rad/sec = 1/RC

The Muscle Pumps attached then are **[modelled as Inductors shown here.](http://www.ipedr.com/vol8/2-E10043.pdf)**

[image]